# CrawlSpider approach to return variable, and unhashable type list error within Scrapy

Tags: python, scrapy

I currently have the following Spider, which inherits from CrawlSpider in Scrapy, however, I'm having trouble understanding some of the errors coming back, or indeed, what the heck I'm doing.

The intent is the following:

Crawl example.com with a broad crawl of 10 links via the spider.
Extract Links from each page of those ten links for further processing (inside parse items) for another part of my program. Pass that data back.

The 'another part of my program' is called like this:

```
t = CrawlerProcess(get_project_settings())

def crawl_site(self):
        
          data = []
          crawler = self.t.create_crawler(MySpider)
          crawler.signals.connect(self.item_scraped, signal=signals.item_scraped)
          self.t.crawl(MySpider, data)
          self.t.start()
          print(data)

          return []
```

You can see here how I'm passing a data list, to get a data list out. I tried all sorts of weird and wonderful mechanisms (including signals) to try to achieve this, but passing in that argument, appending to it, seemed to be the only way to programmatically return. This isn't a CLI program, so dumping stuff to disk isn't an option.

First things first, the error appears to be an internal one with Scrapy. I've tried, yielding single values, not yielding at all. What should I be yielding if anything? How do I get rid of that error in a very simple program?

Second of all, what is the defacto standard way of getting the crawled data back to the main caller? MY approach seems hacky at best. Within a web application here, I just want to return some of the crawled stuff over HTTP - and would preferably not do some Pipeline shenanigans or complicate things with databases.

Currently I get the following in the statscollectors internals within Scrapy:

```
 ERROR:scrapy.core.engine:Stats close failure
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "ython3.8/site-packages/twisted/internet/task.py", line 526, in _oneWorkUnit
    result = next(self._iterator)
  File "python3.8/site-packages/scrapy/utils/defer.py", line 195, in __next__
    raise StopIteration
StopIteration

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "python3.8/site-packages/twisted/internet/defer.py", line 892, in _runCallbacks
    current.result = callback(  # type: ignore[misc]
  File "python3.8/site-packages/scrapy/core/engine.py", line 468, in <lambda>
    dfd.addBoth(lambda _: self.crawler.stats.close_spider(spider, reason=reason))
  File "python3.8/site-packages/scrapy/statscollectors.py", line 62, in close_spider
    self._persist_stats(self._stats, spider)
  File "python3.8/site-packages/scrapy/statscollectors.py", line 74, in _persist_stats
    self.spider_stats[spider.name] = stats
TypeError: unhashable type: 'list'
```

The following is my code.

```
class MySpider(CrawlSpider):

    name = "myspider"
    start_urls = ['https://example.com']
    allowed_domains = ['example.com'];
    links = [];
    COUNT_MAX = 10
  
    custom_settings = {
        'ROBOTSTXT_OBEY': False,
        'CLOSESPIDER_PAGECOUNT': COUNT_MAX
    }


    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.data = args[0]
        #print('*********' + self.data)

   
    rules = [Rule(LinkExtractor(tags='a'), callback="parse_items", follow=True)]



    
    def parse_items(self, response):
        link_regex = re.compile('((https?):((//)|(\\\\))+([\w\d:#@%/;$()~_?\+-=\\\.&](#!)?)*)', re.DOTALL)
        links = re.findall(link_regex, response.text)
       
        list_of_hashes_and_urls = [];

        self.data.append('stuff') 

        yield 'abc'


    def spider_closed(self, spider):
        print('*******************************************************closed')
```

Comment: create a [mre].